# Filter by computers that end in "L"

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using the code below to return computers that contain L but is there a way just to filter the ones that end with "L"? I don't want to return any values where the "L" is anywhere else but at the end of the value. TIA

```
 $cmplist=get-adcomputer -Filter "cn -like '*L*'"  -searchbase $ou.distinguishedname -Properties memberof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-like '*L' should give you everything ending with L.